# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests

Im am currently working on a piece of code that appears to be working for several websites but when ran again the website below i get the error. IndexError: list index out of range. At first i though my xpath was invalid but after further research into xpath i know it is correct. My only other though is that i may need to supply a browser user agent ect to simulate a browser accessing the website.

here is the section of code that fails

```
def safeweb(host):
    print "[*] Launching Norton Safeweb plugin against " + host
    url = 'http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=' + host
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text 
    #print html
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)
    #reporting starts here
    summary = tree.xpath("//*[@id='siteSummary']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div")
    #print len(summary)
    print "[*] Summary: " + summary[0].text
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a browser's `User-Agent` string to see if the site is discriminating against scrapers?

Comment: as i mentioned in my initial post this was a thought of mine but no i have not tried it yet, will give it a go though thanks. I will have to read a little more into the requests library first.

Comment: To pass the `User-Agent` header, you add `headers={'User-Agent': '...'}` to your call (after `url`) but judging by your comment on Martijn's answer, you're issue is with your path expression. You get an `IndexError` by also doing the following: `a = []; print a[0]`, so your summary list will almost certainly be empty if you print it.

Comment: Cheers that saved me some time, i noticed that i was being bocked after several runs on another section of code and im assuming that spoofing my browser agent will now solve that. I agree it probably is my expression hat is wrong but i cant see where im going wrong.Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You should really use `r.content`, *not* `r.text` when working with `StringIO` here.

`r.text` gives you unicode, `r.content` gives you raw bytes. Next, there is no need to use `StringIO.StringIO`, `etree.fromstring(html)` will work just fine. Better yet, pass in the *raw* response to `.parse()`:

```
tree = etree.parse(r.raw, parser)
```

and have the parser read the response directly.

If you stil get an `IndexError` exception, then your XPath expression did not match anything in the page. You'll have to save the HTML instead and analyze it manually to see what is different about that page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Martijn. I have taken your advice and employed the use of `etree.fromstring(html)`. I also tried passing the raw respone as you mention however this produced different errors. I have used python to save the html to a file for analysis, to make sure that the html python is getting is the same as what my browser is giving me. It was slightly different however my code is still returning the same error.